# Vectorized date parsing in a pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, text

I have a `pandas.core.series.Series` that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(["1/1/1900 8:00:00 AM", "1/1/1900 8:15:00 PM", "1/1/1900 9:02:11 PM"])
```

I'm trying to just parse out the time and AM/PM indicator, to get something like this: `8:00:00 AM`.

Here's what I have:

```
s.str.split()
```

Which yields:

```
0 ['1/1/1900', '8:00:00', 'AM']
1 ['1/1/1900', '8:15:00', 'PM']
2 ['1/1/1900', '9:02:11', 'PM']
```

From there, it's pretty trivial to do something like this to get what I want:

```
" ".join(s.str.split()[0][1:])
```

Which produces

```
'8:00:00 AM'
```

How can I vectorize this method, though? I have quite a few dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can make an additional vectorised [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) call on the splitted strings:

```
In [141]:
s = pd.Series(["1/1/1900 8:00:00 AM", "1/1/1900 8:15:00 PM", "1/1/1900 9:02:11 PM"])
s.str.split().str[1:].str.join(" ")

Out[141]:
0    8:00:00 AM
1    8:15:00 PM
2    9:02:11 PM
dtype: object
```